# plotting pandas groupby with x-axis in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of time series where the columns are the time values (in order) and each row is a separate series. I also have extra columns that gives the category of each row, which in turn determines the linestyle and the color.

Here's the dataframe:

```
>>> df
                cat (frac_norm, 2, 1)                                                                                                       cluster
month_rel                           -5        -4        -3        -2        -1         0         1          2         3         4          5        
user1   user2                                                                                                                                       
3414845 4232621  -1b          0.760675  0.789854   0.95941  0.867755  0.790102         1  0.588729   0.719073  0.695572  0.647696   0.656323       4
4369232 3370279  -1b          0.580436  0.546761   0.71343  0.742033  0.802198  0.389957  0.861451   0.651786  0.798265  0.476305   0.896072       0
22771   3795428  -1b          0.946188  0.499531  0.834885  0.825772  0.754018   0.67823  0.430692   0.353989  0.333761  0.284759   0.260501       2
2660226 3126314  -1b          0.826701   0.81203  0.765182  0.680162  0.763475  0.802632         1   0.780186  0.844019  0.868698   0.722672       4
4154510 4348009  -1b                 1  0.955656  0.677647  0.911556   0.76613  0.743759   0.61798   0.606536  0.715528  0.614902   0.482267       3
2860801 164553   -1b          0.870056  0.371981  0.640212  0.835185  0.673108  0.536585         1   0.850242  0.551198  0.873016   0.635556       4
120577  3480468  -1b            0.8197  0.879873  0.961178         1  0.855465  0.827824  0.827139   0.304011  0.574978  0.473996   0.358934       3
6692132 5095003  -1b                 1  0.995859  0.738418  0.991217  0.854336  0.936518  0.910347   0.883205  0.987796  0.699433   0.815072       4
2515737 4263756  -1b          0.949047  0.990238  0.899524         1  0.961066   0.83703  0.835114   0.759142  0.749727  0.886913   0.936961       4
707596  2856619  -1b          0.780538  0.702179  0.568627         1  0.601382  0.789116         0  0.0714286         0  0.111969  0.0739796       2
```

I can make the following plot, where I the x-axis are the ordered values of `('frac_norm',2,1)`, the colors depend on the value of `cluster`, and the linestyle depends on the value of `cat`. However, it's row-by-row. **Is there a way to vectorize this, say, by using groupby?**

[image]

*My code for generating image*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

colors = ['r','g','b','c','y','k']
lnst = ['-','--']
cats = np.sort(df['cat'].unique())
clusters = np.sort(df['cluster'].unique())
colordict = dict(zip(clusters, colors))
lnstdict = dict(zip(cats,lnst))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# I first do it by `cluster` value
for clus_val in clusters:
    clr = colordict[clus_val]
    subset = df[df['cluster'] == clus_val]
    # and then plot each row individually, setting the color and linestyle
    for row in subset.iterrows():
        ax.plot(row[1][('frac_norm', 2, 1)], color=clr,
               linestyle=lnstdict[row[1]['cat'][0]]
               )
```

*Code for generating df*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

vals = np.array([['-1b', 0.7606747496046389, 0.7898535589129476, 0.959409594095941,
        0.8677546569280126, 0.7901020186672455, 1.0, 0.5887286145588728,
        0.7190726452719073, 0.6955719557195572, 0.6476962793343348,
        0.6563233814156323, 4],
       ['-1b', 0.5804363905325444, 0.5467611336032389,
        0.7134300126103406, 0.7420329670329671, 0.8021978021978022,
        0.389957264957265, 0.861451048951049, 0.6517857142857143,
        0.798265460030166, 0.4763049450549451, 0.8960720130932898, 0],
       ['-1b', 0.9461875843454791, 0.49953095684803, 0.8348848603625673,
        0.8257715338553662, 0.7540183696900115, 0.6782302664655606,
        0.43069179143004643, 0.35398860398860393, 0.33376068376068374,
        0.28475935828877, 0.260501012145749, 2],
       ['-1b', 0.8267008985879333, 0.8120300751879698,
        0.7651821862348178, 0.680161943319838, 0.7634749524413443,
        0.8026315789473684, 1.0, 0.7801857585139319, 0.8440191387559809,
        0.8686980609418281, 0.7226720647773278, 4],
       ['-1b', 1.0, 0.955656108597285, 0.6776470588235294,
        0.9115556882651537, 0.766129636568003, 0.7437589670014347,
        0.6179800221975582, 0.6065359477124183, 0.715527950310559,
        0.6149019607843138, 0.4822670674109059, 3],
       ['-1b', 0.8700564971751412, 0.3719806763285024,
        0.6402116402116402, 0.8351851851851851, 0.6731078904991948,
        0.5365853658536585, 1.0, 0.8502415458937197, 0.55119825708061,
        0.873015873015873, 0.6355555555555555, 4],
       ['-1b', 0.8196997807387418, 0.879872907246731, 0.961178456344944,
        1.0, 0.8554654738607772, 0.8278240873814314, 0.8271388025408839,
        0.3040112596762843, 0.5749778172138421, 0.47399605003291634,
        0.35893441346004046, 3],
       ['-1b', 1.0, 0.9958592132505176, 0.7384176764076977,
        0.9912165129556433, 0.8543355440923606, 0.9365176566646254,
        0.9103471520053926, 0.8832054560954816, 0.9877955758962623,
        0.6994328922495274, 0.8150724637681159, 4],
       ['-1b', 0.9490474080638015, 0.9902376128200405,
        0.8995240613432046, 1.0, 0.9610655737704917, 0.837029893924783,
        0.8351136964569011, 0.759142496847415, 0.7497267759562841,
        0.8869130313976105, 0.9369612979550449, 4],
       ['-1b', 0.7805383022774327, 0.7021791767554478,
        0.5686274509803921, 1.0, 0.6013824884792627, 0.7891156462585033,
        0.0, 0.07142857142857142, 0.0, 0.11196911196911197,
        0.07397959183673469, 2]], dtype=object) 

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(              'cat', ''),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1), -5),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1), -4),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1), -3),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1), -2),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1), -1),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1),  0),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1),  1),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1),  2),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1),  3),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1),  4),
            (('frac_norm', 2, 1),  5),
            (          'cluster', '')],
           names=[None, 'month_rel'])

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(3414845, 4232621),
            (4369232, 3370279),
            (  22771, 3795428),
            (2660226, 3126314),
            (4154510, 4348009),
            (2860801,  164553),
            ( 120577, 3480468),
            (6692132, 5095003),
            (2515737, 4263756),
            ( 707596, 2856619)],
           names=['user1', 'user2'])

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols, index=idx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use pandas to plot and avoid the loops:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors = ['r','g','b','c','y','k']
lnst = ['-','--']
cats = np.sort(df['cat'].unique())
clusters = np.sort(df['cluster'].unique())
colordict = dict(zip(clusters, colors))
lnstdict = dict(zip(cats,lnst))

# transpose data frame
df1 = df.T

# map colors from colordict to cluster
cmap = df['cluster'].map(colordict).values.tolist()
# create a custom color map and line style
lscm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('color', cmap)
lstyle = df['cat'].map(lnstdict).values.tolist()

# plot with pandas 
df1.iloc[1:12].reset_index(level=0, drop=True).plot(figsize=(20,10),
                                                    colormap=lscm,
                                                    style=lstyle)
```

[image]

## Update (assuming you want both on the same graph)

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

colors = ['r','g','b','c','y','k']
lnst = ['-','--']
cats = np.sort(df['cat'].unique())
clusters = np.sort(df['cluster'].unique())
colordict = dict(zip(clusters, colors))
lnstdict = dict(zip(cats,lnst))

# transpose data frame
df1 = df.T

# map colors from colordict to cluster
cmap = df['cluster'].map(colordict).values.tolist()
# create a custom color map and line style
lscm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('color', cmap)
lstyle = df['cat'].map(lnstdict).values.tolist()

c = df.columns

# not needed for your actually dataframe
# i am just converting your sample data to numeric
for i in range(len(df.columns[1:])-1):
    df[c[i+1]] = pd.to_numeric(df[c[i+1]])

# groupby and get mean of cluster
df2 = df[c[1:]].groupby('cluster').mean()


# create sublots object from matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# add a twin y-axis
ax2 = ax.twiny()

# plot dataframe 1
df1.iloc[1:12].reset_index(level=0, drop=True).plot(ax=ax, figsize=(20,10),
                                                    colormap=lscm,
                                                    style=lstyle)

# create legend for ax
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='center left', borderaxespad=-20)

# subplot df2
df2.plot(ax=ax2, colormap='copper')

# create legend for ax2
handles, labels = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(handles, labels, loc='center right', borderaxespad=-20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I would also need to plot the mean time series of each cluster (not included in the original question, I admit). I could group by `cluster`, get the mean, plot those, and then perform the code above for the individual curves (which is not based on any groupby, but just deletes the cluster information and replaces it with color). But is it possible to combine these two steps?

Comment: @irene see update. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes it is! So basically, just get the mean and transform it to another dataframe, and then plot on the same figure. Thanks!